# AWS CodePipeline + CodeDeploy to EC2 with docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, aws-code-deploy

Hi I've been trying to get autodeployment working on AWS. Whenever there's a merge or commit to repo, CodePipeline will detect it and have CodeDeploy update the tagged EC2 instance with the new changes. The app is a simple node.js app which I want to start with docker-compose. I have installed docker-compose + docker on the EC2 instance already and enabled CodeDeploy Agent.

I tested the whole process and it is mostly working except for the part where CodeDeploy fails the deployment because it is unable to run the command `docker-compose up -d` in my ApplicationStart portion of the `appspec.yml`. I get the error `docker compose cannot be found` which is kind of weird because in the BeforeInstall script I download and install docker + docker-compose and set all the permissions. Is there something I'm missing or it is just not meant to happen with CodeDeploy and EC2?

I can confirm when I SSH into the EC2 instance and use the command `docker-compose up -d` in project root directory it works, but as soon as I try to run the docker-compose command in the script portion of the appspec.yml it fails.

The project repo is here, just in case there's anything I missed: https://github.com/c3ho/simple_crud

Comment: If you ssh to the instances, is the docker-composed installed? Maybe its localted in a non-default folder, not avaliable in `PATH` when CD agent runs?

Comment: @Marcin Yep, everything is installed, I just got it working. I removed almost all my old revisions in S3 except for 1 of them and restarted the EC2 instance. It is miraculously working after that...